# Does "behaviour" describe exact output?

Tags: engineering, behavior

I know, this question was asked in a slightly different way. But I didn't find it helpful. Sorry, long text.

I'm new in a company and my work concerns graphics and numerical computation. My supervisor, who trains me and decides about my work being accepted or not, has a very specific understanding of "behaviour" with respect to software (requirements) engineering which I wouldn't share and never heard of before. In fact, I even have problems with it because it makes writing tests cumbersome while we are using TDD. Probably slows down (future) development. I wonder if this is just something I didn't learn in Computer Science at University.

My supervisor's definition *excludes generic output and disallows writing generic test cases* because it defines behaviour to be *very concrete output* (visual output in my case) and if a pixel changes visually (different sampling resolution of the same curve), it's not the same behaviour anymore but different behaviour. The official requirement is to show a curve "smoothly" with line segments ("smoothly" is not formally defined).

I have made early parameter decisions (sampling rate, maximum radiuses of the curve) which I would rather change now but this would mean to compute very new reference values for (almost) all tests I have written so far for different requirements. All of them test against fixed output that depends on constant implementation parameters.

By this definition, behaviour or requirements don't seem to be abstract properties of the output but concrete output values and implementation only seems to be the instance of an algorithm to obtain specific output which makes the behaviour definition implementation-agnostic. Test cases should be taylored to compare output against exact references, exact number of sampled points, etc. This didn't make even sense in the beginning due to numerical errors. Fortunately, I was allowed to use a tiny tolerance for floating point comparisons.

I told that I have a different notion of behaviour but the *view of my supervisor is that its used understanding is the general and correct definition in software engineering.*

I'd like to know, if "behaviour = output" is just a subjective comprehension of an informal "behaviour" definition as one only learns in a software engineering institute or whether this is a formal official definition of "behaviour" in Software Engineering Discipline / Research.

Comment: "view of my supervisor is that its used understanding is the general and correct definition in software engineering" - there's no such thing. There's only definition of something given in a certain context. One definition may be suitable for some purposes, and not for others. In terms of making use of polymorphism (and LSP), and in terms of maintainability and writing non-brittle tests, insisting that "behavior" is the concrete thing that the function does (in terms of implementation) is useless. You have to make a distinction between abstract outputs (and relationships) and internal details.

Comment: Seems to me that you have a more sophisticated understanding of this than your supervisor does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, the behaviour of a program is essentially its output. What else is there to test?

The point seems rather to be that your supervisor has a much narrower view than you of what the **requirements** of your system are. He thinks that it has to produce exactly one well-known pixel matrix, while you take the more liberal view that the users care about the curve looking smooth, so any output that looks smooth should be OK.

Depending on what the greater context is, this may or may not be the case. Certainly there is no *consensus* in the community whether either attitude is the "right" one. But what there probably *is* is constraints, circumstances or hidden agendas that you may not be aware of.

For instance, is the conflict perhaps about *workload*? How can your organization actually be sure that your results satisfy the requirements? Judging the acceptability of viewgraphs is a hard task and has to be done manually by human beings, so changing the criterion of the tests may introduce risk or additional work that no one is willing to approve. (Compare this to a minor change in a medical device; each such change usually requires an expensive re-certification of the entire device even if it had "obviously" nothing to do with its medical function.)

In short, rather than arguing words (nearly always useless), try to find out whether the underlying reason goes deeper than "We've always done it this way"/"My way is the right way". Hidden agendas can be exposed and worked with. "My way" attitudes usually can't; it is often simpler to change jobs than to change the mind of someone who hasn't been contradicted or too long.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Your comparison with the medical device is good. I don't know how good it compares though. Indeed, I didn't think about deeper Agendas. In my case, it's my own module that I created and is supervised. I'm a student and the work contract ends this month. I was concerned that after my time developers would need additional effort in writing new tests. So after aproval I didn't change any constant parameters to save effort.

Answer (score 5):

> "smoothly" is not formally defined

Here's your problem. You are looking for requirements that can be generalized and your supervisor can't provide them. Sounds like no one knows. What happens when no one knows is religious adherence to what was published before. You are free to change the stuff no customer sees. But can't change what they can.

This is a bad situation. It comes from poorly defined requirements and a lack of will to endure the pushback that comes from change.  But it happens. It happens to the point that you can buy testing tools that look for pixel differences.

Does this mean your supervisors definition of behavior is wrong? No. Is yours? No. The difference comes from what behavior you care about.

Your supervisor sees the pixels of the curves as set in stone. That doesn't redefine the meaning of the words "output" or "behavior". That explains the business situation you're in.

Or at least how your supervisor see's the business situation. That might be real. It might be a misperception.

I've faced a similar situation in an accounting program. Not only did we have to account for "half pennies", we had to put remainder pennies on the exact same months that a previous program put them. This wasn't simply a "business decision". This was dictated by law.

Your instincts about how this limits the flexibility of your code are spot on. But sometimes reality doesn't care about your best practice. Cut your supervisor some slack until you're sure which is happening.

But, if that is happening, it should be documented in your requirements.

Comment: Thanks. So both kinds of expectation can be considered to be behaviour. Your accounting program example is also interesting. I understand that there are many programs where exact output is a perfectly suitable behaviour definition, also for numerical computing or graphical applications. In my case, it's a software component that we defined together. In university, we treat requirements often as mathematical formulas which can be proven. I like to have formal definitions because it removes ambiguity so that's why I was wondering.

Comment: @ChrisoLosoph in the real world sometimes the only up to date requirements are in the code.